# Write values in app.config file

Tags: c#

can anyone please help me how can I set/store values in the app.config file using c#, is it possible at all?

Comment: Did you google this at all?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What kind of value is it you wan't to store, and when? Generally it's not really recommended to store Application-wide values (like strings or ints) in the App config.

Comment: Asking a question that seems stupid by pros is all right, everybody starts with the beginning. However, not even taking a simpe google search is just lame.

Comment: I tried and also googled, tried few ways, but was getting no luck. that's why i asked so..

Comment: Since you seem new to all this I want to add that the settings will need to be inside your <application name>.exe.config file. If you try to get or set from a dll (i.e. class library project or any other project except mstest projects from I have seen) it won't work. It WANTS your application exe file! You will need hackery otherwise. To be clear I am referring to using the ConfigurationManager for this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using App.Config to store values in `<add Key="" Value="" />`  or CustomSections section use ConfigurationManager class, else use XMLDocument class.

For example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="server" value="192.168.0.1\xxx"/>
    <add key="database" value="DataXXX"/>
    <add key="username" value="userX"/>
    <add key="password" value="passX"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

You could use the code posted on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SystemConfiguration.aspx)

Answer (score 55):

Try the following code:

```
    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);
    config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("YourKey", "YourValue");
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
```

It worked for me :-)

Comment: Thanks, the namespace is System.Configuration.  So System.Configuration.Configuration config = ....

Comment: "Access to the path is denied" when i tried to install it. But when i try it in visual studio it works fine. Can you help me.

Answer (score 33):

On Framework 4.5 the AppSettings.Settings["key"] part of ConfigurationManager is read only so I had to first Remove the key then Add it again using the following:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);

config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("MySetting");
config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("MySetting", "some value");

config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

Don't worry, you won't get an exception if you try to Remove a key that doesn't exist.

This [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/77b87843-ae0b-463d-b50e-b6b8e9175e50/write-to-appconfig-at-runtime-very-urgent?forum=csharpgeneral) gives some good advice

Answer (score 31):

```
private static string GetSetting(string key)
{
    return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
}

private static void SetSetting(string key, string value)
{
    Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    configuration.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;
    configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full, true);
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
}
```

Comment: I had to add configuration.AppSettings.Settings.Add(value); before configuration.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value; to get this to work when the .config file was empty.

Comment: When using `Settings.Add()`, if the entry doesn't exist, it will be added, if it already exists, the value will be added to the existing value(s) separated by a comma. E.g. after calling `Settings.Add("myKey", "test")` 4 times, your entry will become: `<key = "myKey" value = "test, test, test" />`

Comment: ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings"); was the key for me, if you don't do that, reading newly written values won't work.

Comment: I would recommend using `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(configuration.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name)` instead of the hard coded string.

Answer (score 11):

As others mentioned, you can do this with `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Settings`. But:
Using `Settings[key] = value` will not work if the key doesn't exist.
Using `Settings.Add(key, value)`, if the key already exists, it will join the new value to its value(s) separated by a comma, something like
`<add key="myKey" value="value1, value2, value3" />`

To avoid these unexpected results, you have to handle two scenario's

- If entry with the given key exists? then update its value
- if entry with the given key doesn't exist? then create new entry(key,value)

Code

```
public static void Set(string key, string value)
{
    var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    var entry = config.AppSettings.Settings[key];
    if (entry == null)
        config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, value);
    else
        config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;

    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
}
```

For more info about the check `entry == null`, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868726/check-if-key-exists-in-namevaluecollection).
Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 7):

For a .NET 4.0 console application, none of these worked for me. So I used the following below and it worked:

```
private static void UpdateSetting(string key, string value)
{
    Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.
        OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    configuration.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;
    configuration.Save();

    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
string filePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("settings.app.config");

var map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = filePath };
try
{
    // Open App.Config of executable
    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    // Add an Application Setting if not exist

        config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("key1", "value1");
        config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("key2", "value2");

    // Save the changes in App.config file.
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

    // Force a reload of a changed section.
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
}
catch (ConfigurationErrorsException ex)
{
    if (ex.BareMessage == "Root element is missing.")
    {
        File.Delete(filePath);
        return;
    }
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: This response is uniquely helpful in that it shows how to open an arbitrary named config file and not just *.exe.config files; unlike other responses.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);            
config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;
config.Save();
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can - see [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx)

> The ConfigurationManager class
>   includes members that enable you to
>   perform the following tasks:
>
> - Read and write configuration files as a whole.

Learn to use the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library), they should be your first port-of call for a question like this.

Answer (score 2):

```cs
//if you want change
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);
config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;

//if you want add
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);
config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("key", value);
```

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this for a while and finally figured it out on my own.  I didn't find any help at the time, but wanted to share my approach.  I have done this several times and used a different method than what is above.  Not sure how robust it is, but it has worked for me.

Let's say you have a textbox named "txtName", a button named "btnSave" and you want to save the name so the next time you run your program the name you typed appears in that textbox.

1. Go to Project>Properties>Settings and create a setting -

- name = "Name"
- type = "string"
- scope = "user"
- value you can leave blank.

Save your settings file.

2. Go to your form where textbox and button exist.  Double click your button and put this code in;

```
    //This tells your program to save the value you have to the properties file (app.config);
    //"Name" here is the name you used in your settings file above.
    Properties.Settings.Default.Name = txtName.txt;
    //This tells your program to make these settings permanent, otherwise they are only
    //saved for the current session
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

3. Go to your form_load function and add this in there;

```
    //This tells your program to load the setting you saved above to the textbox
    txtName.txt = Properties.Settings.Default.Name;
```

4. Debug your application and you should see the name you typed in.
5. Check your application debug directory and you should see a .config file named after your program.  Open that with a text editor and you will see your settings.

Notes -

- "Name" refers to the actual name of the setting you created.
- Your program will take care of creating the actual XML file, you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: There is no Project>Properties>Settings