# Variable in c# resource

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I am working on a project and I need a kind of variable that save the value and after restarting the program, the value won't get refresh.

For example:
Home Page of a web browser that when you change it, it will save and after restarting the application, it won't reset to the first Home Page Address.

I thought that I can do it using application properties settings

```
Properties.Settings.Default.
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Is this a variable per user, or a global setting for the entire application?

Comment: What didn't work? If the property you added is a Application level property you cannot write it.

Comment: Suggestion: use [isolated storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx "MSDN reference article") to persist user settings.

Answer (score 0):

If the setting is application wide, and not per user, you can use the `AppConfig` to store the value. A similiar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758598/write-values-in-app-config-file).

Sample code copied from [Amol M Kulkarni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1933917/amol-m-kulkarni):

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);
    config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("YourKey", "YourValue");
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
```