# How to introduce dynamic variables in app.config file in c# wpf project

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf project which uses trace listeners to record debug information. The tool is used among a number of people and each of them write out the log file in their specific home directory. What I need to achieve is store all log files in a common dir accessible to all users but the file name should be appended with the user name using the tool in that session. For example I tried this:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
        <listeners>
            <add name="MyListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="Z:\commondir\MyTool-logs\"+WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString()+"toollog.log"/>
            <remove name="default"/>
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Basically I want to dynamically assign a different name to the log file based on the user name. However the above code gives me a build error saying the namespace prefix is not defined. How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible. However, you will need to rewrite sections of your app.config file at runtime, see [Write values in app.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758598/write-values-in-app-config-file).