# Write a section in app.config file

Tags: c#, .net

I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758598/write-values-in-app-config-file) about making changes to the app.config file using ConfigurationManager. This seems to write values under `<appSettings>` in the file.

I feel my question might be a very similar change, but I can't quite work out how to do it.

I've defined a `configSections` element in my app.config file, for example `<section name="Example".../>`, and in the config file it's been given some value:

`<Example file="C:\temp\".../>`.

If I use the command `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Example")`, I can get this value.

I wondered, is there a way to change this value at runtime? So I'd like to use `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Example")` at a later point, and have the new (changed) value returned - if this is possible? Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting that information in the config-file is only one step to achieve what you're looking for.

Your `<Example>`-node is a custom section, that's unknown at that time. For enabling the ConfigurationManager to parse your section to an actual object at runtime, you'll have to define your section as a class deriving from `ConfigurationSection`:

```
public class ExampleSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("file", IsRequired = true)]
    public string File
    {
        get
        { 
            return this["file"]; 
        }
        set
        { 
            this["file"] = value; 
        }
    }
```

For a complete example, please have a look at [this comprehensive MSDN-article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for this! Yes I've checked and I have an `ExampleSection` with `set`. If I cast the result of `GetSection` as `ExampleSection`, make the change, and use `config.Save`, will the edit I made locally be saved to the config file?

Comment: Not being able to try it myself right now, I'd _guess_ that should work. Just give it a try ☺

Answer (score 3):

You can check this link , it's a good example for your issue :

[update appsettings and custom configuration sections in appconfig at runtime](http://yizeng.me/2013/08/31/update-appsettings-and-custom-configuration-sections-in-appconfig-at-runtime/)