# How to write NLog configuration to app.config programmatically with C#

Tags: c#, config, nlog

I need to check whether NLog section exists in my app.config and add it if it doesn't.

The app.config should contain a simple NLog configuration like

```
<configSections>
<section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
```

```
<variable name="myvar" value="myvalue" />
<variable name="globalLevel" value="debug" />

<targets async="true">
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate} mylogfile ${environment:COMPUTERNAME}.log" />
</targets>

<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="${globalLevel}" writeTo="logfile" layout="${longdate} ${level} ${message}" />
</rules>
```

I cannot seem to find a method in NLog API which writes to config file.
I can load the Config in many ways, for example

```
var config = new NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration("NLogTest.exe.config");
```

Then I can add/modify the config adding targets, rules, etc., but how do I write it to my config file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write values in app.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758598/write-values-in-app-config-file)

Comment: this doesn't help as I need a custom nlog section not AppSettings

Comment: Others also wish to serialize the in-memory NLog-configuration and save to file: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/4517 . I would probably focus on saving NLog-config-variables into a custom `NLog-user.config` and then have standard `NLog.config` including the user-file: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/XML-config-include-Example

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/4722